# Must $q$ be analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

I have a continuous function $q:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$. An interesting property of this function is that

$$F(s) = \frac{e^{-q(s)}q(s+1)}{1-e^{s-q(s)}}$$

which also takes $\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$, can be analytically continued to an entire function on $\mathbb{C}$.

Because of this, I wonder:

> > Must $q$ be analytic on $\mathbb{R}^+$?

If it helps, $F(s)$ satisfies the flippant equation:

$$F(s) = e^{F(s-1)e^{s-1}}$$

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo? Why not write it easier as $F(s) = \dfrac{ q(s+1)}{e^{ q(s)}-e^{s }}$ then ? But no way to derive your flippant equation.

Comment: It's not hard to see that any continuous $\bar{q}: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $q(1) = F(0) (e^{q(0)} - 1)$ can be extended to some continuous $q: \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the whole equation, by induction on the integral part of $s$.

Comment: Is your flippant equation actually a functional equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. $F$ does not put enough constraints on $q$.

Suppose that $F$ is a given analytic function, and let $q_0:[0, 1]\to \mathbb R_+$ be continuous. Extend $q_0$ to a function on $\mathbb R_+$ using the recurrence
$$q(s+1) = (e^{q(s)}-e^s)F(s).$$
In general, $q$ will not be continuous or positive. One an write down conditions for that, but they are not needed to answer this question.

Let $q$ be one function that satisfies all assumptions. Let $q'_0=q|_{(0,1]} + g$, where $g$ is a non-negative continuous function on $[0,1]$ with $g'(0)=g'(1)=0$, CBS extend $q'_0$ to a function on $\mathbb R_+$ as sketched above. If $q$ is analytic but $g$ not, then $q'$ will not be analytic either.

Comment: For example, take $F=0$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko you are right, that is the easiest example, unless the OP wants $F$ to be strictly positive.